# Do US passport holders need more than 6 months validity on their passports to be allowed entry into the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens

I'm holding American passport when I enter the States on Sep 22 2012, with a passport that has the expiry date on Mar 2 2013. So it has slightly less than 6 months validity left, about 5 months and 9 days.

Will this be a problem? Or can US citizens enter the States with or without 6 months validity left on their passport?

Comment: Recall too that you can quite easily renew that US passport, in whatever country you are living.  So if you're living in Germany, Thailand or whatever (you have a few passports) - consider just renewing the US passport there in that country (just go to the embassy web site).  Though, there is something to be said for renewing passport from country X actually in country X, the "where was it issued" question is more straightforward then.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly can enter the United States as a US citizen even if your passport has less than 6 months of validity left.

(For non-US-citizens, it depends on whether their country is in the ["six-month club"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7986/583), i.e. exempt from the the six-month rule. A *lot* of counties are exempt from it.)

Comment: (I'd guess a US citizen can enter their own country even with an *expired* passport... not sure about that though.)

Comment: Technically a US citizen can enter the US without a passport at all - it just makes it difficult to prove that you are a US citizen!